# Authenticate to Azure Secure Service Fabric using Powershell without having to enter credentials

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

Anyone has any idea how to authenticate to Secure Service fabric which has AAD configured using Powershell without getting prompted for user credentials?
I am trying to run a script as VSTS task and it need to authenticate to Secure Service Fabric. I tried using Connect-ServiceFabricCluster with -AzureActiveDirectory, ServerCertThumbprint parameters. But it prompts for User credentials. I don't see any parameter where i can pass user name and password in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Include **SecurityToken** parameter into Connect-ServiceFabricCluster command. **When connecting with AzureActiveDirectory, the specified security token is used directly for authentication and authorization rather than performing interactive user login.**
Here is an example of how to get a token -

```
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id"
$credentials = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential]::new($UserName, $Password)
$authContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new($authority)
$authResult = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($clusterApplicationId, $clientApplicationId, $credentials) 
$Token = $authResult.Result.AccessToken

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -AzureActiveDirectory -SecurityToken $Token -ConnectionEndpoint "your_cluster_name.location.cloudapp.azure.com:19000" -ServerCertThumbprint "your_server_cert_thumbprint"
```

Comment: I tried this. But it still prompts me for the user credentials.

Comment: @Ssutar Ok then, did you specify SecurityToken parameter in  Connect-ServiceFabricCluster? When connecting with AzureActiveDirectory, the specified security token is used directly for authentication and authorization rather than performing interactive user login

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a built in task "Service Fabric PowerShell script" instead and use "Cluster Connection" property in it to configure the connection endpoint securely? 
"Cluster Connection" allows both AAD and Cert based authentication methods in standard manner rather than keeping the passwords in the scripts, open to leak.